# Оптимизация компрессии "JPG" в Java

Tags: java, изображения, jpeg

Доброго времени суток !

Есть `метод`, который обрезает изображение. Использую я для нарезки следующую функцию:

```
BufferedImage imageTile = resizedImage.getSubimage(x, y, getSquareWidth(ImageZoomQuantity),
                            getSquareHeight(ImageZoomQuantity));
```

После этого я беру эту нарезанную часть и конвертирую в `byte[]`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(imageTile, "jpg", baos );
                    baos.flush();
                    byte[] imageTileInByte = imageTile;
                    baos.close();
```

И результат я записываю в БД.

Проблема в том, что это если делать это таким способом (приведенным выше), то время на запись в БД увеличивается.

Решил проверить в каком месте больше всего в моей программе затрачивается времени. Поставил несколько `long End, long start` и выяснилось то, что больше всего времени уходит на компрессию. 
Если изменить параметр `"JPG"` на `"PNG"` затраченное время уменьшается, но размер `БД` увеличивается, что не есть хорошо.

Можно ли как нибудь обойтись без компрессии ? 
Если ли `функция`, которая бы заменила `.getSubimage()`? Потому что как я понимаю, она оперирует байтами, а не изображением, и тогда получается что в моем коде происходит две ненужные компрессии.

**P.S** про запись данных в `БД` я в курсе, что записывается **путь** а не сам **файл**. Так что не будем открывать тут дискуссию на эту тему.

Всем добра !

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать для сжатия библиотеку turbojpeg. При некоторых условиях она работает аж в 4 раза быстрее чем ImageIO.write

Comment: А не подскажите ли Вы, при каких именно условиях ?
Моя проблема подходит под описание ?

Comment: Если бы Вы еще подсказали туториал для установки этой библиотеки на Ecipse, был бы вообще благодарен ! Битый чай ищу, не могу найти (

Comment: Целевая платформа, старенький линукс ядро 2.4, OpenJDK 1.6, https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo

Comment: Вот [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443933/Ошибка-в-компиляции-tjcompressor-java) создал специальную тему для поиска ошибки компиляции

Comment: Кстати, разницы между моим примером и с использованием библиотеки вообще никакой =)