# Ошибка при компиляции TJCompressor, Java

Tags: java, изображения

*Скачал* и *установил* `библиотеку libjpeg-turbo`. 
Все делаю так, как написано в [документации](http://downloads.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.1.3/api/org/libjpegturbo/turbojpeg/TJCompressor.html)
Вот то, что я делаю:

```
TJCompressor tjc = new TJCompressor(imageTile, imageTile.getWidth(),
    0, imageTile.getHeight(), TJ.PF_RGB);
tjc.setJPEGQuality(100);
tjc.setSubsamp(TJ.SAMP_420);
byte[] jpg_data = tjc.compress(0);
```

Вот ошибка:

> java.lang.Exception: Unsupported BufferedImage format     at
>   org.libjpegturbo.turbojpeg.TJCompressor.setSourceImage(TJCompressor.java:232)
>     at
>   org.libjpegturbo.turbojpeg.TJCompressor.(TJCompressor.java:106)
>     at Images.cropTilesFromImage(Images.java:147)   at
>   Builder.writeDataToDataBase(Builder.java:46)  at
>   Form$2.widgetSelected(Form.java:101)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
>     at Form.run(Form.java:35)   at Form.main(Form.java:139)

**Проблема решена.**
проблема была в использовании разных палитр цветов.

**P.S**  Если кто нибудь захочет использовать данную библиотеку - милости прошу писать в комментариях, я расскажу с чего начать и как сделать. Целый день сегодня убил на это.

Comment: А это точно весь стектрейс? У вас там первой строкой идет сразу `org.libjpegturbo.turbojpeg.TJCompressor.setSourceImage`, но это же вроде бы код библиотеки, а не ваш? Добавьте ваш код, который ошибку вызывает, и если там не очевидно — укажите строку, номер которой первым номером в стектрейсе.

Comment: Исправлено ! И ошибку испарил тоже.  
А ругается в моменте вызова конструктора, так как я понял, на изображение (в параметре) которое. И почему то у [этих ребят](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965399/libjpeg-turbo-java-encode-jpeg) все работает

Comment: что, сами ответ нашли?

Comment: Вопрос исправил, а не ошибку ) к сожалению

Comment: Ну, у ребят-то другой конструктор вызывается. У Вас их код "один в один" работает?

Comment: @avp все исправил. Ошибка была в том, что в картинках были разные палитры цветов. и это ему не нравилось ! Как закрыть можно тему ?

Comment: Лично я думаю, что стоит написать краткий ответ о решении на свой же вопрос и через некторое время (где-то в правилах все это расписано) принять его. Т.к. это может оказаться полезным кому-нибудь еще. А вообще, посоветуйтесь в чате (или задайте вопрос на Мете, что следует делать в такой ситуации).